# How do I delete all instances of an object that has an association that has already been deleted at the command-line in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model `Comment`

```
Comment(id: integer, body: string, notified: boolean, user_id: integer, stage_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

A comment `belongs_to : stage`.

So when I assign a comment, say with ID12 to the local variable `comment12` in my Rails console, I get something like this:

```
comment12.stage => #<Stage id: 19, project_id: 8, user_id: 1, name: "Wedding", created_at: "2011-02-25 09:05:35", updated_at: "2011-02-25 09:05:35">
```

However, before I setup the dependency on the associations to destroy all comments when a stage was deleted, I have some errant comments left in the db.

So how do I delete all comments, from the Rails console, that have a stage_id that no longer exists ?

Is there a quick command I can run that makes it easy to do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Comment.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN stages ON comments.stage_id = stages.id").where("stages.id IS NULL").each do |comment|
  comment.destroy
end
```